# Convert text/data into x, y arrays?

Tags: database, matplotlib, feature-engineering

I have the following text as the output of my program:

```
Size: 31        Mflops/s: 355.10        Percentage: 0.79
Size: 32        Mflops/s: 370.89        Percentage: 0.83
...
Size: 767       Mflops/s: 360.15        Percentage: 0.80
```

and I want to get an X array = [31, 32, ... 767] and a Y array = [355.10, 370.89, ..., 360.15].

I can't copy-paste values vertically like the snippet above, so I can't extract values easily. The output comes with spaces like above.

I would then put these into matplotlib for easy plotting.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used
http://www.molbiotools.com/textextractor.html

(input: "Size: ")

followed by

https://delim.co/#

to get exactly what I needed.